# The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home","params":..."} was not handled by any navigator. Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home","params":{"user":{"id":"VUUpROQPtKaXVef15e5XhxXNLrm1","email":"anto22e@gmail.com","fullName":"snertp0"}}} was not handled by any navigator.
>
> Do you have a screen named 'Home'?

Tengo este problema cuando intento loggear o registrarme, no se como solucionarlo. He intentado varias formas que he encontrado pero no logro dar con la solución, Gracias!

Esto es todo el código que utilizo en si, entonces no entiendo por que me dice que no existe la Screen Home, si la estoy utilizando. He estado revisando varias veces todo el código pero no encuentro donde puede estar ese fallo, ya que creo que lo estoy llamando todo correctamente.

RegistrationScreen

```
import {Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import {app} from '../firebase/DataBaseConfig';
import Home from './HomeScreen';

export default function RegistrationScreen({navigation}) {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('');

  const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Login');
  };

  const onRegisterPress = () => {
    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      alert("Passwords don't match.");
      return;
    }
    app
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((response) => {
        const uid = response.user.uid;
        const user = {
          id: uid,
          email,
          fullName,
        };
        const usersRef = app.firestore().collection('users');
        usersRef
          .doc(uid)
          .set(user)
          .then(() => {
            navigation.push('Home', {user: user});
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Full Name"
        placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
        onChangeText={(text) => setFullName(text)}
        value={fullName}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholder="E-mail"
        placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        value={email}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
        secureTextEntry
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        value={password}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
        secureTextEntry
        placeholder="Confirm Password"
        onChangeText={(text) => setConfirmPassword(text)}
        value={confirmPassword}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onRegisterPress()}>
        <Text>Create account</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>
        Already got an account? <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress}>Log in</Text>
      </Text>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );
}
```

LoginScreen

```
import {Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {KeyboardAwareScrollView} from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import {app} from '../firebase/DataBaseConfig';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

export default function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Registration');
  };

  const onLoginPress = () => {
    app
      .auth()
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then((response) => {
        const uid = response.user.uid;
        const usersRef = app.firestore().collection('users');
        usersRef
          .doc(uid)
          .get()
          .then((firestoreDocument) => {
            if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
              alert('User does not exist anymore.');
              return;
            }
            const user = firestoreDocument.data();
            navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {user});
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(error);
          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
      style={{flex: 1, width: '100%'}}
      keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
      <TextInput
        placeholder="E-mail"
        placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        value={email}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <TextInput
        placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
        secureTextEntry
        placeholder="Password"
        onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
        value={password}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        autoCapitalize="none"
      />
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onLoginPress()}>
        <Text>Log in</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View>
        <Text>
          Don't have an account?{' '}
          <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress}>Sign up</Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  );
}
```

App.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import LoginScreen from './components/screens/LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './components/screens/HomeScreen';
import RegistrationScreen from './components/screens/RegistrationScreen';
import {decode, encode} from 'base-64';
import {firebase} from './components/firebase/DataBaseConfig';
if (!global.btoa) {
  global.btoa = encode;
}
if (!global.atob) {
  global.atob = decode;
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        {user ? (
          <Stack.Screen name="Home">
            {(props) => <HomeScreen {...props} extraData={user} />}
          </Stack.Screen>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Registration" component={RegistrationScreen} />
          </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );

  if (loading) {
    return <></>;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users');
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      if (user) {
        usersRef
          .doc(user.uid)
          .get()
          .then((document) => {
            const userData = document.data();
            setLoading(false);
            setUser(userData);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            setLoading(false);
          });
      } else {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    });
  }, []);
}
```

HomeScreen

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
FlatList,
Keyboard,
Text,
TextInput,
TouchableOpacity,
View,
} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../styles/styles';
import {firebase} from '../../components/firebase/DataBaseConfig';

export default function HomeScreen(props) {
const [entityText, setEntityText] = useState('');
const [entities, setEntities] = useState([]);

const entityRef = firebase.firestore().collection('entities');
const userID = props.extraData.id;

useEffect(() => {
 entityRef
   .where('authorID', '==', userID)
   .orderBy('createdAt', 'desc')
   .onSnapshot(
     (querySnapshot) => {
       const newEntities = [];
       querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         const entity = doc.data();
         entity.id = doc.id;
         newEntities.push(entity);
       });
       setEntities(newEntities);
     },
     (error) => {
       console.log(error);
     },
   );
}, []);

const onAddButtonPress = () => {
 if (entityText && entityText.length > 0) {
   const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
   const data = {
     text: entityText,
     authorID: userID,
     createdAt: timestamp,
   };
   entityRef
     .add(data)
     .then((_doc) => {
       setEntityText('');
       Keyboard.dismiss();
     })
     .catch((error) => {
       alert(error);
     });
 }
};

const renderEntity = ({item, index}) => {
 return (
   <View style={styles.entityContainer}>
     <Text style={styles.entityText}>
       {index}. {item.text}
     </Text>
   </View>
 );
};

return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
   <View style={styles.formContainer}>
     <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       placeholder="Add new entity"
       placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
       onChangeText={(text) => setEntityText(text)}
       value={entityText}
       underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
       autoCapitalize="none"
     />
     <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onAddButtonPress}>
       <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Add</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   {entities && (
     <View style={styles.listContainer}>
       <FlatList
         data={entities}
         renderItem={renderEntity}
         keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
         removeClippedSubviews={true}
       />
     </View>
   )}
 </View>
);
}´´´
```

Comment: Ahí indica que intentas hacer una navegación a una ventana Home, que no incluyes en tu código

Comment: Si la tengo, pero se me olvido enseñarla aqui, un momento

Comment: No te genera error al importar un componente Home de Homescreen que no exportas, no debería estar como en loginscreen que importas y navegas a HomeScreen

Comment: Podrias explicarlo mejor, no entiendo lo que me quieres decir. Perdona las molestias

Comment: `import Home from './HomeScreen';`, pero en Homescreen no exportas ese, y navegas a Home, `navigation.push('Home', {user: user});`.  en loginscreeen si importas y navegas a Homescreen `navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {user});`

Comment: vale entiendo lo que me quieres decir, pero sigue sin funcionar, no funciona ni el LOGIN, ni el register, pero si funciona la navegacion entre login y register

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116302/discussion-between-jose-and-eduardo-jaramillo-licea).